# Running total of line length while drawing in ArcGIS for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, line, measurements

Is there a way to display the running total length while editing and drawing a new line in ArcGIS for Desktop?

I have a PDF with hand drawn lines representing hedgerows and the total length that each should be. These are not straight so using the CTRL + L shortcut to create a straight line segment doesn't quite cut it. I just want to see a running total while drawing the line, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcMap 10.8, it is shown along the bottom:

[image: Line Length]